# Setting DataContext on MinWindow using async await

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using async/await to load the data for a UserControl. The UserControl receives Data through Main Window. Below is my MainWindow.xaml.cs file:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MainViewModel _viewModel;

    public MainWindow(MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        DataContext = _viewModel;

    }

    private async void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await _viewModel.LoadAsync();

    }
}
```

I am initialising main window in App.xaml.cs like below:

```
var bootstraper = new Bootstrapper();
        var container = bootstraper.Bootstrap();
        var mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        mainWindow.Show();
```

I am using Autofac and my Bootstrapper class looks like:

```
public class Bootstrapper
{
    public IContainer Bootstrap()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<MainWindow>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<NavigationViewModel>().As<INavigationViewModel>();
        builder.RegisterType<LookupDataService>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.RegisterType<FriendDataService>().As<IFriendDataService>();
        builder.RegisterType<FriendOrganizerDbContext>().AsSelf();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Binding to UserControl in MainWindow.xaml:

`<view:NavigationView DataContext="{Binding NavigationViewModel}" />`

NavigationViewModel:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}"
              DisplayMemberPath="DisplayMember">

    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

When I put breakpoints in code I am able to fetch data from Db and see that the property that I am binding is being populated with required data but I see nothing in the UI.

I understand that the `DataContext = _viewModel;` is getting executed even before _viewModel is being populated with required info. But I would like to know how to overcome this problem. What is the correct way of setting the DataContext to something that is being returned by async/await call.

Oh I am following Building an Enterprise App with WPF, MVVM, and Entity Framework Code First from Pluralsight.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post you xaml code? Especially the part where you are binding to your data

Comment: @taquion I have updated the question by adding the binding part.

Answer (score 1):

problem is with your NavigationView datacontext binding.

```
<view:NavigationView DataContext="{Binding NavigationViewModel}" />
```

Since your NavigationView is added inside the MainWindow, it's trying to find the NavigationViewModel property in the MainViewModel, as MainViewModel is set as DataContext for MainWindow.

You can set the DataContext of NavigationView same as you have done for MainWindow in the NavigationView constructor and in the NavigationViewModel constructor call the LoadAsync function to fetch the specific data needs to show in the NavigationView.